# Angle Proof Inside Circle

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry, angle

The vertex of angle $\angle BAC$ lies inside of a circle. Prove that the value of angle $\angle BAC$ is equal to half the sum of angle measures of the arcs of the circle confined inside angle itself and inside the angle symmetric to it through vertex $A$.

So I don't understand how to prove this. I've already drawn a diagram but I can't figure out how to prove this.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Please add diagram to the post

Comment: It didn't come with a diagram, so would you like me to add the one I drew?

Comment: Yes, anything that you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint: Draw a line parallel to $\overline{AB}$ through the center.  Show that the two arcs on the circle between the two parallel lines are congruent.

Comment: Note there are three cases: (a) O lies on $AB$ (or $AC$), (b) $O$ lies inside $\triangle ABC$ and (c) $O$ lies outside.  Use case (a) to prove (b) and (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $BD$ and $CE$ be chords of the circle and $BD\cap CE=\{A\}$.

Thus, $$\measuredangle BAC=\measuredangle BEA+\measuredangle EBA=\frac{1}{2}\hat{BC}+\frac{1}{2}\hat{DE}.$$